PostgreSQL Update Query Taking Too Long Using CREATE TABLE UPDATE Approch
I have a PostgreSQL query that uses a CREATE TEMP TABLE approach to update a table, but it is taking much longer than expected to execute. The query is supposed to finish in around 15 minutes, but it's still running after 1 hour. I tried increasing temp_buffers from 1 GB to 16 GB, but this didn't help.
When monitoring the server resources during the query execution, I noticed the CPU usage is consistently at 95-100%, and RAM usage is around 70-80%.
Server Specifications:
PostgreSQL version: 15
Cores: 4
RAM: 32 GB
Disk Space: 250 GB (50% free)
OS: Linux Ubuntu 22.04

PostgreSQl Specifications:
shared_buffers: 16GB
work_mem: 64MB
maintenance_work_mem: 2GB
effective_cache_size: 16GB
max_wal_size: 1GB

detailed configuration: pg_settings



Table Name
Row Count
Size




source_switchdata_tmp_details
12,065,981
19 GB


source_npcidata_tmp_details
12,689,251
18 GB


source_aepscbsdata_tmp_details
3,501,858
6.432 GB



BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE source_switchdata_tmp_details RENAME TO source_switchdata_tmp_details_og;
CREATE TABLE source_switchdata_tmp_details AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (A.uniqueid) A.transactiondate,
        A.cycles,
        A.payout,
        A.transactionamount,
        A.bcid,
        A.bcname,
        A.username,
        A.terminalid,
        A.uidauthcode,
        A.itc,
        A.transactiondetails,
        A.deststan,
        A.sourcestan,
        A.hostresponsecode,
        A.institutionid,
        A.acquirer,
        A.bcrefid,
        A.cardno,
        A.rrn,
        A.transactiontype,
        A.filename,
        A.cardnotrim,
        A.uniqueid,
        A.transactiondatetime,
        A.transactionstatus,
        A.commission,
        A.overall_probable_status,
        A.details_id,
        A.recon_status_3,
        A.probable_recon_status_1_to_2,
        A.probable_recon_status_1_to_3,
        A.probable_recon_status_3,
        A.recon_created_date,
        A.is_adjustment,
        A.adjustment_type,
        A.priority_no,
        A.is_payload_created,
        A.recon_key_priority_1_1_to_2,
        A.recon_key_priority_1_1_to_3,
        A.recon_key_priority_2_1_to_2,
        A.recon_key_priority_2_1_to_3,
        A.process_status,
        A.reconciliation_date_time,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS recon_updated_date,
        CASE
                WHEN C.recon_key_priority_1_2_to_1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Reconciled'
                ELSE 'Not Reconciled'
        END AS recon_status_1_to_2,
        CASE
                WHEN D.recon_key_priority_1_3_to_1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Reconciled'
                WHEN D.recon_key_priority_2_3_to_1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Reconciled'
                ELSE 'Not Reconciled'
        END AS recon_status_1_to_3,
        CASE
                WHEN (C.recon_key_priority_1_2_to_1 IS NOT NULL AND D.recon_key_priority_1_3_to_1 IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Reconciled'
                WHEN (D.recon_key_priority_2_3_to_1 IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Reconciled'
                ELSE 'Not Reconciled'
        END AS overall_recon_status
FROM source_switchdata_tmp_details_og A
        LEFT JOIN source_aepscbsdata_tmp_details C ON (A.recon_key_priority_1_1_to_2 = C.recon_key_priority_1_2_to_1)
        LEFT JOIN source_npcidata_tmp_details D 
        ON (A.recon_key_priority_1_1_to_3 = D.recon_key_priority_1_3_to_1) 
        OR (A.recon_key_priority_2_1_to_3 = D.recon_key_priority_2_3_to_1);
DROP TABLE source_switchdata_tmp_details_og;
ALTER TABLE source_switchdata_tmp_details
ADD CONSTRAINT source_switchdata_tmp_details_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uniqueid);
COMMIT;

Additionally, there are no indexes on the columns involved in the join (recon_key_priority). When I remove the one join from the query, it executes within 10 minutes.
Query Plan for CREATE TABLE
Unique  (cost=6563725.85..4473887467620.09 rows=12066620 width=2259)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=6563725.85..4473887437453.54 rows=12066620 width=2259)
        Join Filter: (((a.recon_key_priority_1_1_to_3)::text = (d.recon_key_priority_1_3_to_1)::text) OR ((a.recon_key_priority_2_1_to_3)::text = (d.recon_key_priority_2_3_to_1)::text))
        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=6563725.85..7969082.59 rows=12066620 width=2188)
              Workers Planned: 2
              ->  Sort  (cost=6562725.82..6575295.22 rows=5027758 width=2188)
                    Sort Key: a.uniqueid
                    ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=302203.79..1242931.06 rows=5027758 width=2188)
                          Hash Cond: ((a.recon_key_priority_1_1_to_2)::text = (c.recon_key_priority_1_2_to_1)::text)
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on source_switchdata_tmp_details a  (cost=0.00..915793.58 rows=5027758 width=2155)
                          ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=283965.02..283965.02 rows=1459102 width=33)
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on source_aepscbsdata_tmp_details c  (cost=0.00..283965.02 rows=1459102 width=33)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1184989.72 rows=12689248 width=66)
              ->  Seq Scan on source_npcidata_tmp_details d  (cost=0.00..972840.48 rows=12689248 width=66)
JIT:
  Functions: 18
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true

I tried changing the PostgreSQL configuration, but it didn't work. I noticed that the Block I/O Hit Ratio was very low, less than 1% at some points, making it feel like the query was not running at all. Essentially, this issue was happening.
Update:
I created indexes on the recon_key_priority columns beforehand, so my CREATE TABLE UPDATE query took only 4 minutes, thanks to @chris-maurer suggestion.

I think you said it yourself, "there are no indexes on the columns involved in the join" .  One thing, if your 'D1' and 'D2' subqueries do not overlap you can combine them into a single join with a compound ON condition.  That might save you something.  Even if they do overlap you can use logic to disambiguate the scenarios.  Don't dip into the same table twice if you don't have to.

Pls boil down only to the one critical SQL. Post the complete query, not with variable and "...". Add basic information about the table DDL. The execution plan seems to be not correct, e.g. the table source_switchdata_tmp_details_og is missing.

You join whole tables without a selective where conditions, so basically you do not want an index access, but the usage of hash joins and sequential scan. Here seems to be the recommendation to make only one join with an OR predicate contra-productive as it opens nested loops which is for 12M row a clear nogo. Return back to two equi-joins that will be performed as hash joins.
